# Como pegar variavel de um arquivo de outro site por cURL

Tags: php, libcurl

Boa tarde pessoal.
Estou com uma dúvida, tipo sou iniciante e estou usando o cURL para pegar uns dados de um site.
Gostaria de saber se consigo pegar dados de uma pagina por outra pagina porque se eu for acessar normal da erro 404.

Exemplo:

Estou no site x: https://site.com/videos/noads.php?video=ProjetoX

No site x, tem um iframe que liga para esse link só que não consigo acessar pois da 404.

Mas buscando pela source, eu consigo achar o site e olhar o codigo da pagina..

Minha pergunta é sera que eu consigo pegar esse Source link?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desde já obrigado pessoal.
E desculpa se postei em local errado ou algo do tipo.

Comment: Eu não vou passar pois se o fizer me colocarei em posição legalmente punível, mas se procurar na internet tem um txt com todos esses links de iptv.

Comment: Entendo sua posição, só queria colocar no meu app, pois esses canais públicos cai em 1 dia.. Mas obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Assim, tem várias formas de fazer isso, essa é uma delas por cURL, entretanto não seria necessário fazer curl para subtrair o parâmetro:

```
<?php
class Filter 
{
    public static function getExternalUrl($url_method, $info = false)
    {

    $result = explode('?video=', $url_method, 2);
    $video = (isset($result[1])) ? $result[1] : null;
        try {
            $mime_type = null;
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_method);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            list($mime, $charset) = explode(';', curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE));
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
           curl_close($ch);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $mime = null;
            $charset = null;
            $result = file_get_contents($url_method);
        }
        if ($info) {
            return array('file' => $result, 'mime' => $mime, 'charset' => $charset, 'video' => $video);
        } else {
            return $result;
        }
    }
}
//apenas o retorno sem o vídeo
$data = Filter::getExternalUrl('https://site.com/videos/noads.php?video=ProjetoX');
//resultado completo com vídeo
$data2 = Filter::getExternalUrl('https://site.com/videos/noads.php?video=ProjetoX', true);

print_r([$data, $data2]);
```

Comment: Opa, obrigado pela resposta amigo.
Como relatei no tópico sou bem iniciante, coloquei o codigo no meu arquivo e executei deu um erro..

Error: https://prnt.sc/10yl4wd
Codigo: https://prnt.sc/10yl6ly

Para ser mais exato, o link do iframe da 404, como eu disse mas se eu acessar igual no print da postagem, eu consigo achar o valor, source = "link" e abrir.. só queria pegar esse valor, tem como eu conseguir?

Comment: No caso, vc precisa habilitar cURLno seu apache. Parece que está desabilitado, estes são exemplos para php 5 e php 7 caso seja linux: `sudo apt-get install php7-curl` ou `sudo apt-get install php5-curl`, mas vc pode usar a função  `<?php php_info(); ?>` e checar se ela está habilitada.

Comment: O curl deve aparecer como [algo assim](https://prnt.sc/111lz8b) no seu php_info.